# how to create ssrs report with day/week/month parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I need to create ssrs report with day/week/month parameter.
I have two filter as @start_time and @end_time.

I would like to enter date manually.

ı would like also another parameter as @latest as dropdown and @latest parameter should has day, week and month.

Could you please help me how can ı create store procedure and how can ı set properties of parameter to create @latest parameter?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to enter the date range manually? SSRS will automatically do this for you if you setup the parameter as a Date.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do for this is add a column in your data set with the value of the variable. Now it will be the same on every line, but you do not need to import it into your tablex/matrix. Where every want it, maybe the title? Right click and add a place holder. Then double click the place holder to edit it. GO to Data sets, and select the one with your column, chose First(ColumnYouWant). Then when it run it will take the first value from that column, which is always your date you want. Similarly you can do this if you want to show summary level data at the top, using SUM() or AVG() or whatever you want. The same technique will work for your End value.